# Bean with generic field that is not always used

Tags: java, generics

This is a curious situation: I have a bean like this that store some information and I need generics, because the field "data" can contain different types of data.

```
public class Request<T> {

    private String name;
    private Integer code;
    private T data;

    /* Getter and setters */
}
```

The fact is that "data" is not always used and sometimes it can be null. And if I want to avoid raw types I have to define a type anyway, like this:

```
Request<Object> req = ....
```

Is there a better way of doing that, where I can both 1) Avoid raw types 2) Have a generic data field in my request objects ???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should think in a different way: In your case a `Request` not always has associated data. Modelling this with `null`-values is a bad decision, because you have to check for this every time you want to use your data.  At some point you want to handle `Request` without data in a different way then `Request` with data.

Maybe you should make your `Request` to an interface containing Methods like `getName()` and `getCode()` and create two concrete classes `RequestWithData<T>` and `RequestWithoutData` implementing this interface. Then you can check on creation of an `RequestWithData<T>`-instance, if a non-null data is provided. Furthermore, you can express in your method signature that you require a `Request` with data or without data. This leads to a more clean design and avoids your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the request type, use `Request<?>` in your declaration.
If the request is empty (meaning there is no type, which can be set as data), declare it as `Request<Void>`

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [Void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) type, e.g.

```
Request<Void> req = ...
```

or a [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
Request<?> req = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider to change object hierarhy. If you dont use data in some cases, maybe you should have two objects:

```
class Request {

    private String name;
    private Integer code;

    /* Getter and setters */
}

class DataRequest<T> extends Request {
    private T data;

    /* Getter and setters */
}
```

and use:

```
Request req1 = new Request();
Request req2 = new DataRequest<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new 'Optional' type in Java 8. It was made specifically for cases like these. If you cannot, for whatever reason, use Java 8 yet, the Google Guava library also implements that type. Check this example : https://gist.github.com/9833966

Comment: You still have to use a type parameter on your Optional.

Comment: Yes of course, but you will never have to abuse 'null' and the intent is clearly communicated to users of the class.